# how to group the checkbox in container using angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, checkbox

I'm really not sure how to group the checkbox in angular js which gives looks as shown in the reference image attached here.
I'm able to only show list of checkbox but not as shown below.

[image]

thanks

Comment: Wrap them with a div and give it a border? Not angular related issue at all, imo.

Comment: Give the checkboxes a  `width: 48%` , and then give them `float: left;`.

Comment: not related to angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating them with `ng-repeat` you can try to use `ng-class-odd` to display different style for your checkboxes. You should be looking into CSS, *but I gave my attempt at it with this* example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkboxes = [
    {"name":"Dehi","value":false},
    {"name":"Kolkata","value":false},
    {"name":"Munbai","value":false},
    {"name":"Pune","value":false},
    {"name":"Chennai","value":false},
    {"name":"Kochi","value":false}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .row {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #DDD;
  }
</style>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="x in checkboxes" ng-class-odd="'column'">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.value">{{x.name}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```